# How to add a serilog logger to a GenericHost Project in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I am using generic host pattern in my project. I need a logger to file specially a rolling file like Serilog. How can I add it to certain logger configuration to the host builder.

In generic host we can add log configuration such as debugger and console. But I want to use a logger to file with specific options. I don't know how to do so.

Which way is the best practice for?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile) and [this](https://ondrejbalas.com/using-serilog-with-asp-net-core-2-0/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to both answers, I need to use both `Serilog.Extensions.Hosting` and `Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile`.  Then it needs to create a logger object so it can be added to host builder, As shown below :

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.RollingFile(
                outputTemplate: outputTemplate,
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information,
                pathFormat: Path.Combine(loggingDirectory, "systemlog-{Date}.text")
            .CreateLogger();
```

Note that `pathFormat` argument are useful and important.It consists of path and format which is described adequately in [Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile)( Filename format specifiers). Here i use {Date} format after path which means : It creates a file per day. `Filenames` use the yyyyMMdd format.

After creating logger with such a config it needs to be added into `HostBuilder` like this:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureLogging((context, builder) =>
            {
                builder.AddConsole();
                builder.AddSerilog(logger);
                //....<- some other option here
            })
            .Build();
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's another example, I'm hoping this provides a complete example for anyone in need:

- .NET 7 Console App
- Microsoft Generic Host with top-level statements
- Uses a Bootstrap Logger for capturing startup exceptions
- Loads the Logger from IConfiguration

**Program.cs**

```
using ConsoleUI;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Default", LogEventLevel.Debug)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateBootstrapLogger();

try
{
    HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();
    
    builder.Services.AddLogging(config =>
    {
        config.ClearProviders();

        Logger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        config.AddSerilog(logger);
    });

    builder.Services.AddHostedService<App>();
    IHost app = builder.Build();
    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Information",
        "Azure": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz}|{Level:u3}|{SourceContext}|{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "logs/ConsoleUI-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 15,
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz}|{Level:u3}|{SourceContext}|{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "ConsoleUI"
    }
  }
}
```

**App.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ConsoleUI;

public class App : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly ILogger<App> _logger;

    public App(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime,
               IConfiguration configuration,
               ILogger<App> logger)
    {
        _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
        _config = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Yield(); // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36063
                await Task.Delay(1000); // Additional delay for Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime messages
                await ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception!");
            }
            finally
            {
                _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
            }
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogTrace("Hello, Trace!");
        _logger.LogDebug("Hello, Debug!");
        _logger.LogInformation("Hello, World!");
        _logger.LogWarning("Hello, Warning!");
        _logger.LogError("Hello, Error!");
        _logger.LogCritical("Hello, Critical!");

        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```

**Nuget Packages**
[image]

**Output**
[image]

Comment: thank you. Can you please check if the `cancellationToken` parameter should be re-used by the `StartAsync` method?

Comment: I don't believe so.  The cancellationToken provided by the StartAsync() method is used to indicate only if the start process has been aborted.  The cancellationToken for StopAsync() is a different token, signifying the StopAsync() method has been aborted.  If you wanted a cancellationToken inside of ExecuteAsync(), you should create a separate CancellationTokenSource, and perhaps call .Cancel() as the first line in the StopAsync() method, to signal to ExecuteAsync(), that the process is stopping.  Let me know if that's what you are asking by re-use of the token.

Comment: thank you, that's exactly I expected to have there, as the `BackgroundService` class (see the code snippet below) is using this input parameter to create a _`stoppingCts` and pass it to `ExecAsync()` method:

`// Create linked token to allow cancelling executing task from provided token
            _stoppingCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);`

Comment: need to add `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` nuget package for this to work.  (for the `.Configuration()` extension method).  serilog docs kind of are lacking.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need [Serilog.Extensions.Hosting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting/).

```
public static IHost BuildHost(string[] args) =>
    new HostBuilder()
        .UseSerilog() // <- Add this line
        .Build();
```